# I can't create table with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I created a jpa xml `EntityManagerFactory`. After running tomcat, and Hibernate create table in console, but when I checked the database , I didn't see the table. What's the problem ?

[image]

[image]

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.hospitalmanage.model"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all models are in package `com.example.hospitalmanage.model`

- User
- user_diagnosis
- user_treatments
- user_videos

All should be inside the same package.

Comment: Not work. I put in single folder.But hibernation didn't create user table ((